# How to get conversation details in microsoft bot framework for skype?

Tags: node.js, botframework, skypedeveloper

I'm able to get conversation details for webchat using https://webchat.botframework.com/api/conversations/[conversationId]/messages

Service URL for skype channel is https://skype.botframework.com, but I dont find any documentation for getting conversation details

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DirectLine Rest API (see [docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/)).

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own client applications, web chat controls, mobile apps, or service-to-service applications that will talk to their bot.
>   Within the Direct Line API, you will find:
>   An authentication mechanism using standard secret/token patterns
>   The ability to send messages from your client to your bot via an HTTP POST message
>   The ability to receive messages by polling HTTP GET
>   A stable schema, even if your bot changes its protocol version

You need to enable the DirectLine channel for your bot on (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naFd5.png))

You don't have to access each specific channel endpoint separately, you can do it all (with some limitations) through the DirectLine API.

---

**Start a New Conversation**

`POST /api/conversations`

**Get Messages in a Conversation**

`GET /api/conversations/{conversationId}/messages`

**Send a Message**

`POST /api/conversations/{conversationId}/messages`

The full details are in the docs as linked above.

Hope this helps

Comment: This will work only for conversation that started with DirectLineApi, 
I want conversation history for all channels like skype, groupme, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Sorry I can't upvote your comment as I've only just joined SO.

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific about conversation details and what you're looking for?

Generally, you shouldn't assume those URL's are static BTW; an incoming message from the Bot Framework will have a ServiceURL that should be used for the life of that conversation.  Some services may have multiple ServiceUrl's that they give out for different users.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: I want chat history, which I'm able to get it for `webchat` but not for `skype, groupme, etc`